# How do I create a polymorphic 1:1 relationships wtih Ember Data fixtures?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, polymorphic-associations

Page has a polymorphic 1:1 relationship with a model called PageContent. PageContent has two subtypes (TextOnly and Video). I want to be able to able to do a findAll for "page" and get all of the content back. What am I doing wrong?

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/mozuza/2/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work: http://jsbin.com/names/1/edit

Only wrong thing I could see is the  App.Page.FIXTURES.

It should be:

```
 App.Page.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Introduction",
    pageContent: 1,
    pageContentType: "textOnly"

  },{
    id: 2,
    title: "Summary",
    pageContent: 1,
    pageContentType: "Video"

  }
];
```

or

```
App.Page.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Introduction",
    pageContent: {
      id: 1,
      type: "textOnly"
    }
  },{
    id: 2,
    title: "Summary",
    pageContent: {
      id: 1,
      type: "Video"
    }
  }
];
```