# How would I fix this one-to-many polymorphic relationship in ember-data?

Tags: javascript, database, ember.js, ember-data

There are four models:

- `Idea` and `Comment`, which extend `Thought`
- `Vote`

Both an idea and a comment can have multiple votes. However, each vote can only relate to one idea/comment.

**Note**: `Idea` is analogous with `Post` for this example.

The solution I came up with is in this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/dayekutedi/1/edit?html,js,output

The above code dies when I try to fetch the vote records. It works fine while getting the ideas. Considering how simple this example is, I'm sure I don't understand polymorphic relationships as well as I think I do. Anyways, any hints as to what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't with the relationships, it was with the fixture data. More information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25371206/3026248.